# Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'global.performance.now') is in react-native-tvOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, apple-tv

I'm creating a React-Native-tvOs app and while running that default template app it shows this error. I followed all the script from react-native-tvOs GitHub page but still, when I tried running it on the Xcode Apple TV simulator, it always throws this error.
This is the script I'm running is from GitHub [react-native-tvOS](https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos) page:-

```
npm install -g @react-native-community/cli
react-native init FinalPOC --template=react-native-tvos@latest
cd FinalPOC && react-native run-ios  --simulator "Apple TV" --scheme "FinalPOC-tvOS"
```

**Screeshot of the Error:**
[image]

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-performance

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error,

1. Remove node_modules with rm -rf `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Then do `npm install`

   It works for me

Answer (score -1):

same error,

Modify this file `react-native/Libraries/Utilities/createPerformanceLogger.js` maybe work.

modify

```
export const getCurrentTimestamp: () => number =
 global.nativeQPLTimestamp ?? global.performance.now.bind(global.performance);
```

to

```
export const getCurrentTimestamp: () => number = Date.now
```

New Version React Native has not set nativeQPLTimestamp to variable nativeQPLTimestamp in global.

Comment: did note resolve the problem for me.